# How can I hide pages from menus in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I only want to show the pages that do not have parents, and link the other pages from their parent pages.

I want to have a simple main menu: Home | Pages | About | Contact

About 8 pages are linked from the Pages page. At the moment, the menu has 12 items, which deforms the layout pretty badly.

I have tried making the pages private, unpublished, and other options, but that doesn't seem to be the way to do it. Is there a way I can just have only parent pages linked in the main menu?

Comment: Does your theme support menus? What do you want: to edit theme or to do it in admin? What have you tried? etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can edit the menu (under the appearance tab in the dashboard). (you may need to add a new menu and assign it to the main navigation menu. It sounds like you have the defaulted menu set-up.

Once you've added a menu and assigned it to the main navigation, you can uncheck "automatically add top-level elements" or its equivalent, and add/remove menu items. You can also change their hierarchy (independent of actual page hierarchy).

Answer (score 2):

It's all so easy these days. Just Go to appearance>menus>click the little triangle next to the listed page name>click remove> don't forget to save ... all done!

Comment: but how to hide without removing ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you didn't set up a custom menu yet. Set up a custom menu first with the desired pages / links. If it doesn't show on your site, check custom memus are enabled in your theme.. this will help you setting up a custom menu: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-navigation-menus-in-wordpress-3-0-themes/